# Collatz sequence in Q

Tags: kdb

I try to implement Collatz sequence in Q (as a beginner's exercise). It is easy to obtain the very first value:

```
collatz:{`long$$[0j~x mod 2;x%2;1+3*x]}
```

The problem is that code above obviously doesn't contain any control structure.
I am aware that I can compute another element by

```
2 collatz/ x
```

...3,4 and so on.. But my attempts to get whole list (sequence) were completely futile...I tried:

```
til 5 collatz/ x
```

and

```
1 2 3 collatz/ x
```

Nothing works...

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to do here, the following will work with your function:

```
collatz\[5;x]
```

This is the "iterate" use case for backslash, in this case performing five iterations on whatever the input "x" is.

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#converge-iterate

```
q)collatz\[5;1]
1 4 2 1 4 2
```

Comment: In order to converge to 1, you can use inifix notation as `(1<>)collatz\ 5` or alternatively as `collatz\[1<>;5]`. Your function can also be simplified by removing the cast and long comparison: `collatz:{$[x mod 2;1+3*x;x div 2]}`

Comment: Glad to hear it. Hope you're enjoying the language, and good luck with your learning!